# Typescript: "type?" is optional in an array, while "undefined" isn't

Tags: typescript

Two signatures I thought were the same are behaving differently from each other:

```ts
type FooType = [ string, number? ]
const fooAr = [ "foo" ] as FooType // compiles
```

```ts
type BarType = [ string, number | undefined ]

// Conversion of type '[string]' to type 'BarType' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other.
const barVar = [ "bar" ] as BarType
```

I wouldn't mind except I'm inferring the type from a library and can't change the signature. Is this how Typescript is supposed to behave?

== Edit

Was hoping it followed the object type behavior:

```ts
type FooType = { foo: string, bar: string | undefined }
const fooOjb = { foo: "abc" } as FooType // compiles
```

Comment: Yep. Not existing and existing with a value of `undefined` are different.

Comment: About your update: that only works because it's a type assertion: https://tsplay.dev/mZXnEw. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47994926/detailed-differences-between-type-annotation-variable-type-and-type-assertion) question for the differences and nuances.

Comment: That makes so much more sense thank you for the link!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`?` and `undefined` are not interchangable.

---

`type FooType = [ string, number? ]`
means that the array can look like this:

> `["hello"]` or `["hello", 123]`

---

`type BarType = [ string, number | undefined ]`
means that the array can look like this:

> `["hello", undefined]` or `["hello", 123]`

Comment: Important to note that this behavior is also seen in [objects](https://tsplay.dev/m0nPaw), but you can turn on `exactOptionalPropertyTypes` to [change that](https://tsplay.dev/wEBzkN).

Comment: Totally right. Thanks for pointing it out @caTS

Comment: Dang! Exactly why I thought it'd behave that way, thanks

Answer (score 1):

`FooType` is using an [optional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#optional-properties), where as `BarType` is using `undefined`.

For why they are different see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46397280/typescript-whats-the-difference-between-an-optional-field-and-a-union-with-und).